# How can I create a heatmap visualization of amino acid attention scores, with each row showing 30 amino acids and attention scores?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bioinformatics

I Want to visualize the attention score of my model for amino acid sequence.
[Like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewxrg.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

amino_acids = ['M', 'L', 'I', 'V', 'N', 'Y', 'L', 'G', 'D', 'L', 'W', 'Q', 'V', 'T', 'Q', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'S', 'L', 'E', 'K', 'R', 'E', 'Q', 'F', 'R', 'G', 'L', 'Y', 'L', 'N', 'K', 'I', 'S', 'E', 'Y', 'S', 'G', 'C', 'I', 'T', 'K', 'S', 'L', 'D', 'E', 'K', 'L', 'L', 'G', 'P', 'I', 'L', 'C', 'E', 'S', 'F', 'F', 'V', 'N', 'G', 'L', 'A', 'Q', 'L', 'Y', 'D', 'K', 'K', 'Q', 'S', 'Q', 'H', 'Q', 'V', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'K', 'R', 'V', 'M', 'Y', 'I', 'V', 'A', 'K', 'E', 'F', 'N', 'A', 'D', 'Y', 'D']
attention_scores = [0.66119576, 0.8003918, 0.7251454, 0.72951543, 0.65185624, 0.70199203, 0.80630046, 0.6887356, 0.6589288, 0.7341603, 0.7876512, 0.7288329, 0.69848996, 0.71069247, 0.67025244, 0.73884994, 0.5722088, 0.8040074, 0.5754876, 0.71131456, 0.6967427, 0.7382109, 0.81139785, 0.8124091, 0.68958503, 0.7973248, 0.81046563, 0.6905091, 0.7415714, 0.70773214, 0.7040749, 0.66361755, 0.75876045, 0.7386744, 0.7828561, 0.7754259, 0.58837545, 0.7422827, 0.8162603, 0.7287266, 0.735986, 0.7265348, 0.7996047, 0.6885884, 0.7867183, 0.7414569, 0.5857099, 0.70292705, 0.76017207, 0.73468393, 0.73548526, 0.7142082, 0.691998, 0.7387566, 0.70642775, 0.7064969, 0.71976453, 0.71234685, 0.6858974, 0.632145, 0.6200939, 0.80994266, 0.70530456, 0.7354963, 0.8044978, 0.80209994, 0.7402193, 0.6048866, 0.73206097, 0.6948871, 0.7328906, 0.8089224, 0.79542226, 0.701279, 0.7086161, 0.80316234, 0.737327, 0.6821824, 0.7155741, 0.7198679, 0.81061196, 0.61442053, 0.8037533, 0.63040495, 0.7192761, 0.76812285, 0.7024652, 0.70812845, 0.80918, 0.64278257, 0.7862615, 0.81110525, 0.77845424, 0.7100564, 0.78630733, 0.8025117]

num_rows = len(attention_scores) // 30
data = np.array(attention_scores[:num_rows * 30]).reshape(num_rows, 30)

plt.imshow(data, cmap='hot', vmin=0, vmax=1)

for i in range(num_rows):
    for j in range(30):
        plt.text(j, i, f'{data[i, j]:.2f}', ha='center', va='center', color='black')

# Step 6: Customize the plot
plt.xlabel('Amino Acids')
plt.ylabel('Rows')
plt.title('Attention Visualization')

plt.xticks(range(30), amino_acids[:30])
plt.yticks(range(num_rows), ['Row {}'.format(row+1) for row in range(num_rows)])

cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Color Scale')

plt.show()
```

I attempted using this script to generate the visualization.

but it produces a plot:

[image: but it produces a plot],

whereas I desire something like:

[image: whereas I desire something like]

Comment: First thing would be to use the same colour LUT on both. Spectral isn't too bad, but thermal is pointless on non-image data like these. You might find that Peano-Koch color LUT makes better use of the colour cube and gives you more contrast between cells. The obvious difference seems to be that the second graph is done a line at a time  and more of them - you should be able to do that easily. The other major difference is that your version seems to have numbers printed in each cell which is distracting. Eliminate the code to do that and it will look much better!

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to create the plot when every row is a separate subplot. Seaborn's heatmap automatically creates annotations colored black or white, depending on the cell color.

Here is some example code.  Note that the example data seems to be missing one entry in `amino_acids`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

amino_acids = ['M', 'L', 'I', 'V', 'N', 'Y', 'L', 'G', 'D', 'L', 'W', 'Q', 'V', 'T', 'Q', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'S', 'L', 'E', 'K', 'R', 'E', 'Q', 'F', 'R', 'G', 'L', 'Y', 'L', 'N', 'K', 'I', 'S', 'E', 'Y', 'S', 'G', 'C', 'I', 'T', 'K', 'S', 'L', 'D', 'E', 'K', 'L', 'L', 'G', 'P', 'I', 'L', 'C', 'E', 'S', 'F', 'F', 'V', 'N', 'G', 'L', 'A', 'Q', 'L', 'Y', 'D', 'K', 'K', 'Q', 'S', 'Q', 'H', 'Q', 'V', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'K', 'R', 'V', 'M', 'Y', 'I', 'V', 'A', 'K', 'E', 'F', 'N', 'A', 'D', 'Y', 'D']
attention_scores = [0.66119576, 0.8003918, 0.7251454, 0.72951543, 0.65185624, 0.70199203, 0.80630046, 0.6887356, 0.6589288, 0.7341603, 0.7876512, 0.7288329, 0.69848996, 0.71069247, 0.67025244, 0.73884994, 0.5722088, 0.8040074, 0.5754876, 0.71131456, 0.6967427, 0.7382109, 0.81139785, 0.8124091, 0.68958503, 0.7973248, 0.81046563, 0.6905091, 0.7415714, 0.70773214, 0.7040749, 0.66361755, 0.75876045, 0.7386744, 0.7828561, 0.7754259, 0.58837545, 0.7422827, 0.8162603, 0.7287266, 0.735986, 0.7265348, 0.7996047, 0.6885884, 0.7867183, 0.7414569, 0.5857099, 0.70292705, 0.76017207, 0.73468393, 0.73548526, 0.7142082, 0.691998, 0.7387566, 0.70642775, 0.7064969, 0.71976453, 0.71234685, 0.6858974, 0.632145, 0.6200939, 0.80994266, 0.70530456, 0.7354963, 0.8044978, 0.80209994, 0.7402193, 0.6048866, 0.73206097, 0.6948871, 0.7328906, 0.8089224, 0.79542226, 0.701279, 0.7086161, 0.80316234, 0.737327, 0.6821824, 0.7155741, 0.7198679, 0.81061196, 0.61442053, 0.8037533, 0.63040495, 0.7192761, 0.76812285, 0.7024652, 0.70812845, 0.80918, 0.64278257, 0.7862615, 0.81110525, 0.77845424, 0.7100564, 0.78630733, 0.8025117]

row_len = 30
num_rows = (len(attention_scores) + row_len - 1) // row_len

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=num_rows, figsize=(10, num_rows))
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    data = attention_scores[i * row_len:(i + 1) * row_len]
    data_len = len(data)
    data += (row_len - data_len) * [np.nan]  # pad to full length
    sns.heatmap(data=[data],
                cmap='turbo', norm=norm,
                xticklabels=amino_acids[i * row_len:(i + 1) * row_len],
                yticklabels=[f'Row\n{i * row_len}-{i * row_len + data_len - 1}'],
                square=True, annot=True, annot_kws={'fontsize': 6},
                cbar=False, ax=ax)
    ax.tick_params(length=0, rotation=0)
plt.colorbar(axs[0].collections[0], ax=axs[:], label='Color Scale')
axs[-1].set_xlabel('Amino Acids')  # label for the lowest x-axis
plt.suptitle('Attention Visualization')  # overall title
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap with rows for amino acid sequence]